# VSTO Projects cannot be built after installing VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

We have several VSTO projects that were created using VS2010.

Recently we installed another visual studio version VS2013 as according to Microsoft several VS versions can exists side by side in a machine.

However when we open up the old projects via VS2010 and try to build we get the following error messages.

The "FindRibbons" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. MineTech.Apps.Excel2010Addin

Any help would be of great help (we would like to keep both VS2010 and VS2013 if possible)

Comment: Just google the error message.  And you'll [find this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/651634/the-findribbons-task-failed-unexpectedly).

Comment: those solutions did not work for me as I get new errors. I have updated post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/848b773a-2933-4371-a98f-f4346c427aed/office-ribbons-wont-load-after-installing-visual-studio-11-developer-preview?forum=vssetup&prof=required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's nearly a year now, but maybe it can help anyone anytime.
I posted a solution to this issue, that worked for me here: [a new build error after making change by replacing version=10.0.0.0 with 11.0.0.0 in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855404/a-new-build-error-after-making-change-by-replacing-version-10-0-0-0-with-11-0-0/33626976#33626976)

Just ignore the main problem in this question and follow my steps.

Good luck!