# a new build error after making change by replacing version=10.0.0.0 with 11.0.0.0 in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, excel-2010, vsto, excel-addins

I got the same problem as [Build Error + Creating VSTO addin for excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376771/build-error-creating-vsto-addin-for-excel-2010)

After making the change according to the solution, I got the new error:

```
 The "InitializeDefaultProperties" task could not be loaded from the   
 assembly 
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, Version=11.0.0.0, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. Could not load file or 
 assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, 
 Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one 
 of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm    
 that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its 
 dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that 
 implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

I have installed VS2013 on the same machine so I change version=12.0.0.0 but I got a new error:

```
 Error  2   The "SetInclusionListEntry" task could not be instantiated from 
 the assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, 
 Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 
 Please verify the task assembly has been built using the same version of  
 the Microsoft.Build.Framework assembly as the one installed on your 
 computer and that your host application is not missing a binding redirect 
 for Microsoft.Build.Framework. Unable to cast object of type  Micro
 soft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.SetInclusionListEntry' to type 
 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask'.
```

Comment: Randomly trying to use a VS2012 file (version 11) on a machine that only has VS2010 available (version 10) is not going to get you anywhere.

Comment: @HansPassant, you mean I should change it back to version=10.0.0.0 ?

Comment: I mean that you should stop doing random things to solve your problem.  Whatever they may be.  You'll just end up with two problems.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I have changed it back to version=10.0.0.0, the same problem as before. Where can I go now ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old post, but maybe I have a solution for you...
I ran into exactly the same problem and I have to tell you that the "InitializeDefaultProperties" exception is not fix-able for VS2010.

First of all:
Make sure that your Visual Studio 2010 installation is not modified, anyway make a clean install just to be sure.

If you modified the **C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets** revert your changes.

If you now try to build your VSTO Project the following error should apppear:

> The "FindRibbons" task could not be loaded from the     assembly
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. Could not load file
>   or   assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one   of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm      that the `<UsingTask>` declaration is correct, that the
>   assembly and all its   dependencies are available, and that the task
>   contains a public class that   implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

**My Solution:** 
--> Open Visual Studio 2010 (you dont need to load a Project) 
--> Go to *Help* an click *About Microsoft Visual Studio* 
--> Check Version

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 
>  10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel 
>  Microsoft
>   .NET Framework 
>  Version 4.5.51209 SP1Rel

If it says **RTMRel** download the **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1** from here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210710

It includes the necessary VSTO and VSTO 4.0 Runtime.

If thats not the Problem, I'm sorry...

Answer (score 0):

As I encountered the same problem upgrading our build server... I am gonna put the solution here in case anyone needs it.

I think the way to solve this is to fix your GAC.

Open the .target file of that tool by notepad and take a look at the UsingTask tag, you should get something like

```
<UsingTask TaskName="InitializeDefaultProperties" AssemblyName=" Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks", Version=11.0.0.0,..., PublicKeyToken=sthsthsth
```

Then, go to your GAC files, e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks

Then, create a new folder: v4.0_11.0.0.0_sthsthsth, 
which is:

`v<.NETFramework Version, mostly 4.0>_<Assembly Version>_<PublicKeyToken>`

And then, put the .dll file of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks in it.
This dll should be obtained when you install VSTO either by directly install (VSTO2010) or by Visual Studio installer

e.g.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll

for Visual Studio 2017 and then directly place the dll inside the folder created

Then this issue should be fixed. Good luck